# SQL Query to choose records where condition is met using EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query which pulls events from my events table.

**Goal**: I want to select events from the events table but first look to see if the signed in user is already attending the event.  **If yes** then do not display that event.

I have a signup table that is a 'transactional' table between 'users' and 'events' tables.  Field 'ID' in 'users' table is PK and its FK is in the 'signup' table under field 'customer'.  Field 'ID' in 'events' table is PK and its FK in the 'signup' table is field 'eid'.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        date,
        '%W, %b %e %Y %l:%i %p'
    ) date,
    date orderByDate,
    shortDesc,
    summary,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    private
FROM
    events
WHERE
    zip = 93101
AND approved = 1
AND date > sysdate();
```

I feel like I need to use the keyword EXISTS to first check and see if the signed in user has a record existing in the 'signup' table but my poor peasant brain can't seem to figure out the query. **Thanks for all help**, everyone has been amazing so far with all my SQL questions.  Still learning a lot. :)

Comment: Where is the `user id` you're fetching events for?

Comment: In the 'users' table there is a field called 'id' and that is the user id.  That same field has a foreign key in the 'signup' table under field 'customer'.  So customer is the same as id in signup and users tables respectively.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `not exists`, since you would like to fetch records that do not have a corresponding record for the given user in the `signup` table:

```
SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W, %b %e %Y %l:%i %p') date, date orderByDate, shortDesc, summary, street, city, state, zip, private 
        FROM events 
        WHERE zip = 93101 
        AND approved = 1 
        AND date > sysdate()
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM signup WHERE signup.eid=events.id and signup.customer=...);
```

Substitute the user id in place of the `...`

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks much for your help.  I knew it was NOT EXISTS and I should have mentioned that, but I still couldn't figure it out. Now I know :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the userId for which you want to fetch events for, your query can look like-

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        date,
        '%W, %b %e %Y %l:%i %p'
    ) date,
    date orderByDate,
    shortDesc,
    summary,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    private
FROM
    events
WHERE
    zip = 93101
AND approved = 1
AND date > sysdate()
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT
        eid
    FROM
        signup
    WHERE
        customer == <your-customer-id>
);
```